# Trouble with order.by('?') .first() to get random content in Django

Tags: python, django

### Update #4:

- **The for loop in `slider.html` is currently not pulling content after the last update. Slider.html was randomized; however, I'm getting four of the same story and the urls are not going to their appropriate detailed view page anymore.**
- List.html has been fixed and is now random.

#### slider.html - This section is still wonky, (updated - 4:19 p.m.)

```
{% for random_article in random_articles %}
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="group visible">
                <div class="sliderItem">
                    <a href="{%url "detailed" slug=random_article.slug %}"><img src="{{random_article.relatedImage}}" alt="" class="sliderPicture"></a>
                    <a href="{%url "detailed" slug=random_article.slug %}"><p class="related">{{random_article.title}}</p></a>
                </div><!-- /.sliderItem -->
            </div><!-- /.group -->
    </div><!-- /.slider -->
        {% endfor %}
```

#### Here is the URL error when I click to detailed view:

```
NoReverseMatch at /last-us
Reverse for 'detailed' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>\\S+)']
```

### New culprits (for why slider.html isn't working)

#### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="list"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="detailed"),
)
```

#### views.py (updated - 4:19 p.m.)

Added `context['random_slider'] = FullArticle.objects.order_by('?')[:4]` but I don't think this is the right approach. So that I can get four different articles vs. four of the same article randomized.

```
from django.views import generic
from . import models 
from .models import FullArticle

# Create your views here.
class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.FullArticle.objects.published()
    template_name = "list.html" 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['random_article'] = FullArticle.objects.order_by('?').first()
        return context

class BlogDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.FullArticle
    template_name = "detailed.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = models.FullArticle.objects.published()
        return context

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['random_articles'] = FullArticle.objects.exclude(
            pk=self.get_object().pk
            ).order_by('?')[:4]
        return context
```

---

## Original Problem

I'm using FullArticle.objects.order_by('?').first() to get a random article from my database, but it's currently giving the same article when I refresh the page. There is probably something missing from my models, view or how I'm calling it (using slice) in `list.html` or `slider.html` that is causing the problem.

### The two parts I'm looking to make random on page load:

#### list.html (changed so that it's {{random_article.}} ) - This section of the problem is fixed.

```
<div class="mainContent clearfix">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Top 10 Video Games</h1>
            {% for article in object_list|slice:":1" %}
            <p class="date">{{article.pubDate|date:"l, F j, Y" }}</p> | <p class="author">{{article.author}}</p>
            <a href="{%url "detailed" slug=article.slug %}"><img src="{{article.heroImage}}" alt="" class="mediumImage"></a>
            <p class="caption">{{article.body|truncatewords:"80"}}</p>
            {% endfor %}
```

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your models here.
class FullArticleQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def published(self):
        return self.filter(publish=True)

class FullArticle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    pubDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    heroImage = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    relatedImage =  models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    body =  models.TextField()
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    gameRank = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = FullArticleQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("FullArticle_detailed", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ["-pubDate"]
```

Comment: Just an aware from Django's official documentation: `Note: order_by('?') queries may be expensive and slow, depending on the database backend you’re using.` Maybe the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354127/how-to-grab-one-random-item-from-a-database-in-django-postgresql) can help you achieve what you want.

Comment: I'm aware that it's probably slow. Still need to solve this problem though. In my case, it's a database that only contains 10 articles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the value of a class attribute at "compile time" and not each time the view is called. Instead, you could do:

```
class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.FullArticle.objects.published()
    template_name = "list.html" 

    def random_article(self):
        return = FullArticle.objects.order_by('?').first()
```

Or:

```
class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.FullArticle.objects.published()
    template_name = "list.html" 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['random_article'] = FullArticle.objects.order_by('?').first()
        return context
```

[update]

> In list html, I only need one random article. In slider.html, I need four random articles, would I just tack on FullArticle.objects.order_by('?')[:4] somewhere in that def get_context_data snippet?

Yes. Make it plural in the view (don't forget to exclude the main article from the side list):

```
class BlogDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.FullArticle
    template_name = "detailed.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['random_articles'] = FullArticle.objects.exclude(
                                          pk=self.get_object().pk
                                     ).order_by('?')[:4]
        return context
```

At the template, do:

```
{% for random_article in random_articles %}
    <div class="sliderItem">
                <a href="{%url "detailed" slug=random_article.slug %}"><img src="{{random_article.relatedImage}}" alt="" class="sliderPicture"></a>
                <a href="{%url "detailed" slug=random_article.slug %}"><p class="related">{{random_article.title}}</p></a>
    </div><!-- /.sliderItem -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The syntax for the second snippet you posted seems right, however, I'm still getting the same article every time I refresh the page. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't see you using `{{ random_article }}` at `list.html`.

Comment: My list.html is now working, I've used {{random.article}} in list.html, which is awesome. Thank you for that. But my slider.html is being randomized, but I'm getting four of the same article, any thoughts?

Comment: you are getting just the first article. If you need 4, 1) name the item `random_articles`, 2) make it `context['random_articles'] = FullArticle.objects.order_by('?')[:4]` and 3) use a `{% for random_article in random_articles %}` inside the template instead.

Comment: In `list html`, I only need one random article. In slider.html, I need four random articles, would I just tack on `FullArticle.objects.order_by('?')[:4]` somewhere in that def get_context_data snippet?

Comment: Yes, Andrew, you got it.

Comment: I've gotten `AttributeError at /
'BlogIndex' object has no attribute 'get_object'` with your updated changes

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo on the `super` call in `BlogDetail`, first parameter should be `BlogDetail` instead of `BlogIndex`.

Comment: I'm wondering if the for loop is correct? It does seem to be grabbing content from the database when I do `{% for random_article in random_articles %}`

Comment: Any thoughts? Before I was getting four of the same article, now with the fixes, while it appears cleaner in `slider.html` it's not actually pulling in any of the content anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67265/discussion-between-paulo-scardine-and-andrew-nguyen).

Comment: Sure thing. I've jumped into the chat.

Answer (score 0):

The generic listview just passes an object_list as context based on the queryset.  In your case it means you have to either change the value of queryset in your view or override the get_context_data method and add your random item to it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data

Comment: Could you expand on your answer with a code snippet.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Sven. The so called "link-only" answers are frowned upon here. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline** (linkrot). Any answer that gets the OP going in the right direction is helpful, brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Comment: Thank you Paulo. It wasn't my intention to be unclear but I get your point. Next time I will add fuller explanations.